# How to compare arrays and negate values?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How to compare two arrays and give the condition that if there is a negative value in the first array, then at the same position in the second array it will negate the value. Is it possible, please?

Example:

arrays a:

```
a=numpy.array([[1, 2, 3],[4, -8, 6],[-10, 8, -12]])
array([[7, 2, 9],
       [8, -11, 4],
       [-10, 18, -12]])
```

array b:

```
b=numpy.array([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]])
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

results

array b:

```
    b=numpy.array([[1, 2, 3],[4, -5, 6],[-7, 8, -9]])
    array([[1, 2, 3],
           [4, -5, 6],
           [-7, 8, -9]])
```

Answer (score 0):

> if there is a negative value in the first array, then at the same position in the second array it will negate the value

The NumPy way to say this is `b[a < 0] *= -1`:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a=numpy.array([[1, 2, 3],[4, -8, 6],[-10, 8, -12]])
>>> b=numpy.array([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]])
>>> b[a < 0] *= -1
>>> b
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4, -5,  6],
       [-7,  8, -9]])
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.sign(arr)` to get the sign of all values.

Sign is defined as-

- 1 for positive values
- 0 for zero
- -1 for negative values

To compare 2 arrays, compare their sign arrays.

```py
a = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3],[4, -8, 6],[-10, 8, -12]])
b = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]])
a_sign = numpy.sign(a)
b_sign = numpy.sign(b)
assert numpy.array_equal(a_sign, b_sign) == False
```

To "transfer" this sign information, you can take absolute value of first array and element-wise multiply sign array. This way, the initial sign of second array does not matter(because we work on absolute values)

```py
a = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3],[4, -8, 6],[-10, 8, -12]])
b = numpy.array([[1, -2, 3],[-4, 5, -6],[7, -8, 9]])
a_sign = numpy.sign(a)
b_abs = numpy.absolute(b)
result = numpy.multiply(b_abs, numpy.sign(a))
expected = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, -5, 6], [-7, 8, -9]])
assert numpy.array_equal(expected, result)
```

Keep in mind that **sign(0) is 0** . Instead of copying the sign, this method will write zero to that position.

Also, this will not work on complex numbers.